# Discord.JS V12 BOT Spams text

Tags: discord, discord.js

I made a command but bot is spamming after command is executed to a channel.

Could you please help me out? It's a simple mistake but I am confused right now. I tried many things..

Code:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (message.channel.id == `912767631344423032`) {
    if (command === "sinfo")
      const server = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#6C8A9D")
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL())
        .setTitle("Server Info!")
        .addFields(
          {
            name: "Όνομα Server:",
            value: `${message.guild.name}`,
            inline: true,
          },
          {
            name: "Δημιουργήθηκε στις:",
            value: `${message.guild.createdAt}`,
            inline: true,
          },
          { name: "Server ID:", value: `${message.guild.id}`, inline: true },
          {
            name: "Server Owner:",
            value: `${message.guild.owner}`,
            inline: true,
          },
          {
            name: "Server Developer:",
            value: `<&@337327678245830666>`,
            inline: true,
          },
          {
            name: "Τόπος καταγωγής Server:",
            value: `${message.guild.region}`,
            inline: true,
          },
          {
            name: "Αληθινά άτομα:",
            value: `${message.guild.createdAt}`,
            inline: true,
          },
          {
            name: "Επίπεδο Επαλίθευσης:",
            value: `${message.guild.verificationLevel}`,
            inline: true,
          }
        )
        .setFooter("Created and Developed by Tana#6969 ❤️")
        .setTimestamp();
    message.channel.send(server);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing the { } for this if:

```
if (command === "sinfo")
```